# Clickable Images fields

Tags: media, uri

When creating new content types, I know I can have an image field, but how do I associate a URL with an image so that when you click on the image, it goes to that node or location? Is the only way to get into the code and surround the img tag with an href tag?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Exchange doug! :)

This is what I believe to be the most popular solution. It's good because it's fairly easy to set up, yet very flexible. You will need the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

1. Add a textfield to the same bundle (content type) as the one holding your images.
2. Create a View
3. Add your link field to the field list, and check "Exclude from display".
4. Add your image field to the field list, scroll down to rewrite results, check "Output this field as a link", and add the link "token", in the "Link path" field. The list of available tokens are listed further down under "Replacement patterns". [image: Example of field rewriting].
5. Save the View, and add it where you want. :)

If you want to know more about Views, you can see a video tutorial series [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120614011405/http://dev.nodeone.se:80/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone).